# React Binding and Populating an Object

Tags: reactjs

I have a React Component which maintains a Local State as shown below:

```
  this.state = {
      user : {}
    }
```

I have 2 textboxes on the screen where I can enter name and age. I am sending the values from the textboxes and populating the user object inside the state as shown below:

```
 onTextBoxChange = (e) => {

   // this.user is a property on the Component declared inside the // constructor
    this.user[e.target.name] = e.target.value

    this.setState({
      user : this.user 
    })
  }
```

Is there a better way of populating the state with the user object which consists of name and age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create an extra variable (`let user =...`) or a member variable (`this.user`).

Just overwrite previous values using spread syntax.

```
  onTextBoxChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };
```

Here is the fully working version on CodeSandBox.
[image: Edit xjkxnzz34p]

Comment: Wow! This is even better solution :)

Comment: @johndoe I was about to delete my answer as Atul's explanation was great (at least I can upvote it )

Comment: Make sure to write `...this.state.user` before setting the `e.target.value`, otherwise, value will not be updated.

Comment: @SungKim Thanks :)

Comment: As @AtulKhanduri mentioned, `...this.state.user` will provide previous values, and `[e.target.name] : e.target.value` will `overwritte` so the **order matters**.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same by following three different ways:

1) There's no need to creating an `this.user` property, instead to can achieve the same by using a local variable. So, the function can be changed to:

```
onTextBoxChange = (e) => {
    let user = this.state.user;
    user[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
        user: this.user 
    })
}
```

2) If you're not using `user` state in input text boxes for value, then you can simply use `this.user` property instead of using a state, which will cause re-rendering.
You can then use the `this.user` when the form submitted, for example.

3) Again, If you're not using `user` state in input text boxes for value, then you can also use [React `refs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and get the value directly from the element when the form is submitted, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: this one tries to be a little too slick I think.  The accepted answer is more declarative, more clear.  
nice point on changing the local variable the OP used.
How are you using `this.user` when form submitted and as the value of the field? `this.user` is  a local variable, like you said, how are you thinking of putting that into the form submit if its not in state or a variable that the rest of the component could reach?

Comment: @ardev Above points are 3 different approaches to achieve the same thing depending upon the situation. `this.user` is **not** a local variable rather declared in the constructor (as OP says). So when the value is changed in the textbox, it is added to `this.user` in its key and when the form is submitted, the values can be fetched from `this.user`.

Comment: @ardev Also, as mentioned in the 3rd point, once the form is submitted, you can use [`refs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get the HTML element and then its value. Doing this, you don't need to manage its state and `this.user`.

Comment: @ardev Also, I never said that `this.user` is a local variable.

Comment: @AtulKhanduri I thought that you were suggesting that OP should forego creating the `this.user` property in the constructor when you said in your first point: 'There's no need to creating an this.user property,'  and that `this.user` should be a local variable when you said, again in your lead point: 'instead to can achieve the same by using a local variable.'
If thats not what you meant then I can see how you can pass that into a ref and use it for form submittal.  Still, think the approach of showing the nested state is a bit more readable, though it appears your solution would work too

Answer (score -1):

You might try this in a parent component:

```
onTextBoxChange = (field, value) => {
        this.setState({user:{
            ...this.state.user,
            [field]: value
        }   
        });
    }
```

and then this in the child component:

```
onNameChange = (e) => {
    this.props.onChange('name', e.target.value)
}
onAgeChange = (e) => {
    this.props.onChange('age', e.target.value)
}
```

Comment: How is it better than the two proposed solutions? Also, I don't think any reason to manage state in the parent component if it can be maintained in a child component.

Comment: only difference between mine and accepted is that the accepted answer encapsulated capturing the `(field, value)`
Your absolute on parent vs child component state is wrong. You dont know if you need to hold it in a parent component or not -- depends where you want to use the data.  Also, you could obviously keep it all in the same component.